# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated doesn't always work?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

What prevents a modal view controller from being dismissed?  I've found dismissModalViewControllerAnimated doesn't always work?  For example this won't work:

```
SettingsViewController* settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *settingsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
[navigationController presentModalViewController:settingsNav animated:YES];     
[navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to do too many navigation animations too close together, they usually won't work. Try doing your dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: after a delay of 0.75 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
SettingsViewController* settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *settingsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
[navigationController presentModalViewController:settingsNav animated:YES]; 
[settingsNav dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If SettingsViewController it's UIViewController then:

```
SettingsViewController* settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:settings animated:YES]; 
[settings dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```